# Show that $f$(sum of log terms) is convex with Jensen's inequality..

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

We have the equation 
\begin{equation}
f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}-\sum_{i=1}^m\log{(b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x})} ,\;\;\; \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } m>n
\end{equation}

where we see that $\textbf{dom}f$ is convex since it is the a halfspace of the hyperplane $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}=b$.

I want to show that $f$ is convex. What is the best approach to do so? Should I differentiate or should I show that Jensen's inequality holds truth?

I tried with Jensen's inequality and for $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2 \in$  $\textbf{dom}f$ and $\theta \in [0,1]$ I begin by \begin{equation}
f(\theta \mathbf{x}_1+(1-\theta)\mathbf{x}_2)<\theta f(\mathbf{x}_1)+(1-\theta)\mathbf{x}_2
\end{equation}
and at some point I get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
-\sum_{i=1}^m\log{(b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^T(\theta \mathbf{x}_1+(1-\theta)\mathbf{x}_2))}<&-\theta \sum_{i=1}^m\log{(b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}_1)}\\&- \sum_{i=1}^m\log{(b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}_2)}\\&+\theta \sum_{i=1}^m\log{(b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}_2)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

From this point forward how can I proceed with Jensen's inequality to show that f is convex?

Comment: Frankly it is *extremely rare* to use nothing but Jensen's inequality or a derivative test to prove convexity. (Unless you're being forced to do so as a homework exercise.) The much better way is to build a proof of convexity from more basic building blocks using principles such as those [outlined in Chapter 3 of this book](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/). So, for instance, you should realize that you have a *sum* of terms, each of which is separately convex.

Comment: This is the book I use to study convex optimization. However in the particular question I am just asked to show that this function is convex. I know I can say it is a sum of convex functions and convexity is preserved under sum operation. I have also showed is it convex with Hessian, Hessian of $f$ is positive for all $\mathbf{x}$. I am just wondering (mostly curious) how can I proceed with Jensen's inequality for this particular function...

Comment: Then you already have an answer to your question *as you have asked it*. There just isn't any reason to derive Jensen's inequality directly at this point. I for one don't consider it helpful at all to *purposefully* take the more difficult path to proof. (Indeed, here's your proof: $f(x)$ is convex, as you have already proven by other means; *therefore*, it satisfies Jensen's inequality. Done.)

Comment: Ok, :) Thank you very much!